# Oracle Webcenter Content : what is the difference between URLs "/wcc" and "/cs"?

Tags: webcenter, oracle-ucm

My company decided to migrate to the *Oracle Fusion Middleware*, and we are starting to use the *Oracle Webcenter* components, especially the *WCC* (v11.1).

We can access our documents via 2 different entry points :

- http://server:port_1**/wcc**
- http://server:port_2**/cs**  *(and this URL is also accessed via RIDC)*

The GUI are very different from one app to the other, but the main functionalities seem to be the same on both of them : I can browse, view, download stored documents, I have access to the metadata, I can do an advanced search or upload a file...

Why does Oracle provide 2 webapps to manage the content ? Why are these URLs on 2 different *Weblogic* servers (or domains) ? Should we use one address rather than the other ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are simply two different GUIs. Some functionality is available in one that may not be available in the other.

Use whatever interface best fits your needs (including what user's may prefer).

/cs/ is for the [native (original) UI](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wcc/webcenter-content-use/GUID-B856E3A1-F2E4-46C4-A11D-ECDDCFDFE26E.htm).

/wcc/ is for the new(ish) [ADF WebUI](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wcc/webcenter-content-use/GUID-276F5312-6415-437A-B47A-9A42012D518F.htm). Also see [this blog post](http://www.mythics.com/about/blog/practical-oracle-webcenter-content-ui).